# Java - JComponent paintComponent()

Tags: java, swing

I am trying to figure out how to `repaint()` a class that extends the `JComponent`. I want to have each class extend `JComponent` and then supply its own `paintComponent()`. (`super.paintComponent()`.  This way I can make a circle class or whatever class that I want to make and then I can `repaint()` it when ever I want to as long as it is added to the `JPanel` that goes in the `JFrame`. Below are all of the code that are needed to run.

**Class 1:**

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JMenu;
import javax.swing.JMenuBar;
import javax.swing.JMenuItem;

public class DDHGenericFrame extends JFrame {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    /* User defined class that is below */
    DDHGenericPanel d = new DDHGenericPanel(); 

    public DDHGenericFrame() {
        initUI();
    }

    public final void initUI() {
        add(d);
        setSize(650, 350);
        setTitle("Lines");
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        DDHGenericFrame ex = new DDHGenericFrame();
        ex.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

**Class 2:**

```
import java.awt.Graphics;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

class DDHGenericPanel extends JPanel {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    DDHGenericPanel() {
        System.out.println("DDH Generic JPanel");
    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        //paint code goes here of whatever
    }
}
```

**Class 3:**

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import javax.swing.JComponent;

public class DDHCircleOne extends JComponent {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    int counter = 0;

    public DDHCircleOne() {
        counter++;
        System.out.println("DDHCircle Constructor");
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g2) {
        super.paintComponent(g2);
        Graphics2D c2D = (Graphics2D) g2;
        c2D.setColor(Color.yellow);
        c2D.fillRect(0, 0, getSize().width, getSize().height);
        if (counter % 2 == 2) {
            System.out.println("RED");
            counter++;
            c2D.setColor(Color.red);
            c2D.fillRect(0, 0, getSize().width, getSize().height);
        } else {
            System.out.println("BLUE");
            counter++;
            c2D.setColor(Color.blue);
            c2D.fillRect(0, 0, getSize().width, getSize().height);
        }
    }
}
```

The above three classes are what I have in my package. I want `DDHCircleOne` to be able to repaint it self whenever an instance of it is created and calls the method `repaint()`. This way I can just make a class that extends `JComponent` and then override the `paintComponent()` and then call `repaint()`.

If I had a button that said repaint in red and another button that says repaint in blue the circle or whatever I had in the frame will repaint itself when the `variableName.repaint()` is called.

doughauf@outlook.com

Comment: Don't do it or are you going to overflow the stack?

Comment: It is only my personal computer so, it won't cause that much of a problem. In Java if you overflow the stack can you just reboot and start over or are there some really nasty things that can happen?

Comment: This way you are doing yourself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    repaint();
}
```

Never invoke repaint() in a painting method. This will cause an infinite loop.

There is no need for you generic panel. You can add a component to any panel.

If you want the color of the circle to change, then you need to change a property of your component. For example you can just use the setForeground(...) method to change the color:

```
//c2D.setColor(Color.red);
c2D.setColor( getForeground() );
```

So when you click on your button you just invoke circle.setForeground(Color.RED);

The setForeground() method of JComponent will invoke the repaint() method on the component for you.

Comment: I forgot about the repaint() in the color paintComponent(). The repaint can be called from anywhere correct. Will it repaint the class if it has a repaint component if it is added to the component.

Comment: I will try this. Do most of the methods repaint the component. When you you have to specifically call repaint()?

Comment: Swing components are designed to repaint themselves when a property is changed. You would use repaint() if you have custom painting and you change a property that isn't currently a property of the component. Still waiting for you to start accepting answers when you get help.

Comment: Hate to ask but how do I accept answers when I get one???? Also I  am wanting to repaint() a component that I have a custom paint then I can just recall repaint() but other ways the component class will just repaint itself.

Comment: So anything that extends the JComponent will have a set up properties that will just repaint automatically. That is the confusing thing sometimes to me is that if a component is changed it then repaints it self, and if you want to custom paint than you can call repaint() with a paintComponent() with code in it.

Comment: @DougHauf , Yes, methods like setFont(), setText(), setForeground() will automatically invoke `revalidate()` (for layout purposes) and `repaint()` (for painting purposes). `and if you want to custom paint...` - you only need to paint your component when you change a property. So you should be adding setProperty1(...), setProperty2(...) type methods to your class and invoke those methods to change a property. Then those methods would invoke revalidate()/repaint(). The repainting of the class should be hidden from the programmer.

Comment: So the method in the class the extends JComponent would be named like setMethod1, setMethod2, setMethod3 and so on. Those classes should invoke the repaint() component.